# in DotNetNuke - Where is the 'Auto Add Portal Alias' option in the database

Tags: dotnetnuke

There is a feature added in DNN 5.6.2 to Auto Add Portal Alias.

I didn't find its record in the PortalSettings data table. How to change it from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the HostSettings table and change the SettingsValue to 'N' for the SettingsName 'AutoAddPortalAlias'. I'm using DNN v7.1+